# Thread Program Log File Creation

Tags: multithreading, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

I performed a simple thread program using [this](http://www.mkyong.com/logging/logback-different-log-file-for-each-thread/) link, but the

log files are not getting created. Can somebody help me out with this?

My Code :

//////////////////////////////Main Class///////////////////////////////

```
package PkgThread;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        int count = 1;
        while(count<=5){
            Head head = new Head();
            head.setName("head-" + count);

            executor.execute(head);
            count++;



        }
        executor.shutdown();
    }

}
```

14:59:12,682 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
14:59:12,683 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
14:59:12,683 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at

```
[file:/D:/PrcSHERM/ProjThread/target/classes/logback.xml]
14:59:12,732 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - debug attribute not set
14:59:12,745 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.SiftingAppender]
14:59:12,748 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [FILE-THREAD]
14:59:12,770 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.MDCBasedDiscriminator] for [discriminator] property
14:59:12,778 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
14:59:12,780 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [STDOUT]
14:59:12,808 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender[STDOUT] - This appender no longer admits a layout as a sub-component, set an encoder instead.
14:59:12,808 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender[STDOUT] - To ensure compatibility, wrapping your layout in LayoutWrappingEncoder.
14:59:12,808 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender[STDOUT] - See also http://logback.qos.ch/codes.html#layoutInsteadOfEncoder for details
14:59:12,808 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [com.mkyong.analyzer.core] to DEBUG
14:59:12,808 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting additivity of logger [com.mkyong.analyzer.core] to false
14:59:12,808 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [FILE-THREAD] to Logger[com.mkyong.analyzer.core]
14:59:12,809 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[com.mkyong.analyzer.core]
14:59:12,809 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to ERROR
14:59:12,809 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[ROOT]
14:59:12,809 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
14:59:12,810 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@fda5bfa - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found where I had gone wrong

I had specified the wrong package name in logback.xml

The package name had to be changed from com.mkyong.analyzer.core to my own package

name. Now, the log files are getting created.

Answer (score 0):

You submit tasks to the `Executor` just to close it directly afterwards. You have to give the `Executor` time to actually execute them, i.e. use [`boolean awaitTermination(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).

Besides: I do not see any logging.

Comment: what logic do I specify in the above method?

Comment: After `executor.shutdown()` just write `executor.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)` and the program will wait for 60 seconds for the tasks to complete. Or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: still,  no log files are getting created. As per the link from where I performed the program, log files should be generated. See here : http://www.mkyong.com/logging/logback-different-log-file-for-each-thread/